# In doxygen documentation how to create a link to a specific line of a file

Tags: line, hyperlink, doxygen

There are several doxygen commands whose purpose is to create links in the documentation ([@link](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdlink), [@ref](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdref)).
I am currently using the [@ref](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdref) command to create a link to a custom file, written in a language not supported by doxygen (xml). 
I would like to alter this link so that it points to a precise line in the file.
Is there a doxygen command that allows to do that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure that `\ref` or `\link` can do this. However, if they could, one problem of adopting this approach is that the links will become invalid if you change the contents of the file you are linking to without changing the link. This is one of the problems of separating source code and documentation.

Rather than linking to a particular line in another file why don't you include the particular part of the file you are interested in in the documentation? You could either:

- include the whole file with [`\include`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdinclude) (there is also [`\includelineno`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdincludelineno)) and just reference relevant parts of it in the text (e.g. "function xxx in the code below"), or
- include snippets of the file where you need to refer to them in the documentation using [`\snippet`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdsnippet).

**Edit**: Alternatively, you could use the [`\dontinclude`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmddontinclude) command which, together with the `\line`, `\skip`, `\skipline`, and `\until` commands allows you to include specific lines/blocks of a particular file. See the example in the `\dontinclude` documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. The `\snippet` command seemed promising, however it only works for code snippets from _source files_, while I want to show data from my _xml resource file_. I cannot add the tags identifying the snippet location to my xml file because doxygen-style comments would "break" it. The use of \include is smart as well, but it is a huge file and I do not want to include it every time (the documentation would be blotted by irrelevant data). However when I use a \ref to my file, I already reference relevant parts, as you suggest. I am just looking for an even better way.

Comment: @wil No problem. I have also added a note on the `\dontinclude` command, which would be better for you than the `\snippet` command since it does not require any tags to be added to your resource file. However, according to the documentation it seems that this command only works on source files (I have not tested this, so am not sure if this is actually the case). You could also include the XML directly in your documentation. Failing this I'm afraid you may just have to live with using your `\ref` method.

Comment: I tried the `\dontinclude` commands and it also works for xml files ! I have settled for this solution and set your answer as "accepted" :-)

Comment: Thanks, glad I could help - knowing that you can document XML resource files in this way is very useful.