# Doxygen Create Link to specific line of code

Tags: c++, doxygen

Before you reference [in-doxygen-documentation-how-to-create-a-link-to-a-specific-line-of-a-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9661243/in-doxygen-documentation-how-to-create-a-link-to-a-specific-line-of-a-file), I already reviewed that and it doesn't answer the question I have.

In doxygen, there are several links created to specific lines of code (assuming code is built when building doxygen output).  The best example is function details as shown below:

[image: Doxygen Code Line Link]

I would like to create similar links for other items that are parsed when doxygen is created.  Specifically, the SDD tags that you see in the picture above.  By creating a link from the SDD tags, or referencing it in the same way doxygen does with "Definition at line 6969 of file AlarmManager.cc", will allow my team to jump straight to the line of code where the SDD is referenced/implemented.  See code example below:

```
case NEBULIZER_INOPERATIVE_EN:  /// @sdd [ALARM_ANALYSIS_SDD_1]
   ConditionEvaluations::SetCondition(C1500);
   AlarmManager::ROperandNameList_.append(tempName = C1500);
   break;
case NOT_NEBULIZER_INOPERATIVE_EN: /// @sdd [ALARM_ANALYSIS_SDD_2]
   ConditionEvaluations::ClearCondition(C1500);
   AlarmManager::ROperandNameList_.append(tempName = C1500);
   break;
case NEBULIZER_DISCONNECTED_EN: /// @sdd [ALARM_ANALYSIS_SDD_3]
   ConditionEvaluations::SetCondition(C1501);
   AlarmManager::ROperandNameList_.append(tempName = C1501);
   break;
```

I tried anchors in the code, but that didn't work.  I don't know how to just reference and create a link to File->code line.

Comment: To be able to give an answer whether or not it is possible at all a small code example is needed (at the moment I don't think it is possible but it might be possible to find a workaround, otherwise it might be possible to define a new command or an extension to an existing  command. It all depends on the requested quantity). Furthermore  the doxygen version you use (1.8.14) is not very old but a bit older, the current version is 1.8.16.

Comment: @albert Updated question with code sample.  The sdd tags are what I would like to link to if possible.  Also, I know I'm on a couple versions back on doxygen, but was there any significant changes to doxygen that I should update it to the latest?

Comment: Difficult problem as we are here at the usage place of of an item. What happens when in this case the item is used on multiple places (with the same \sdd) or is this just to jump somewhere inside the same routine? Have to think about it. Best is to create an issue in the doxygen issue tracker (https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/new) so the request will not get lost (at the moment not a lot of time to think about it).

Comment: @albert I wouldn't care or spend time on multiple places.  First one found would be sufficient and the tags should really have unique values.  Doesn't need to be tied to a routine, but just line of code of occurrence.  Tying to routine is "nice to have" in my opinion.  I will create an issue in github.  Thanks!

Comment: @ls6777 Have you found solution for this?

Comment: @Sergio I haven't seen anything that supports this, but I haven't checked on the latest version of doxygen to see if this capability was added.